# Need to Switch from Mac Thunderbird to Apple Mail. But First I want to backup Mac Thunderbird. How Can I Do It?

Tags: mac, mail.app, backup, email, migration

I recently switched to a new company. As I am the sales head, I receive a lot of emails to look at daily. Earlier I was using Mac Thunderbird as my daily email client but now here it is mandatory to use Apple Mail. So I need to switch from Mac Thunderbird to Apple Mail. The only thing that I require is to backup all my emails before I make the switch so that I don't loose any while migration. I am looking for a quick backup solution that won't take long to do the backup procedure.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You should also include the information on what solutions have you tried. Please read: http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Maybe is quite easier, configure IMAP (if already done), push all importants mails to server syncing your e-mails, configure Mail.app, and you are done. If you dont know what is IMAP, just ask to your IT guy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Time Machine to Backup your emails?

A more elaborate procedure is explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cd2YaBCXpaM

You can also opt for third party applications: http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Utilities/Mail-Backup-X.shtml

I hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the solution George. I tried the Time machine backup thing but it was a long and tiring procedure, instead, I tried the mail backup x application, which was fast and efficient enough to backup my emails safely. And also the inbuilt email converter was a unique thing that I found in this application. It is an all-rounder tool for email backup, restoration, and conversion,

Answer (score -1):

[Here are the instructions to transition from Thunderbird to Apple Mail](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Export_to_Mail.app)

Comment: Just an FYI... Link-only answers are typically down-voted and or closed as links can age and become broken. You should provide a substantial answer either in your own words and or a combination with using quoting as necessary. The bottom line is, your answer, as currently written, is a non-answer by AD and SE standards. See: [How do I write a good answer?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: WOW, have you look how old are the software?? Reference 10.4 as current OS.